# Elixir: Find middle item in list

Tags: list, elixir

I'm trying to learn Elixir. In most other languages i've battled with, this would be an easy task.

However, i can't seem to figure out how to access a list item by index in Elixir, which i need for finding the median item in my list. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your list is a tuple, not a list.

Comment: Do not name variables `list`, `set`, etc.

Comment: The Python part isn't important, it was only to show the concept of what i wanted to do in Elixir.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this question because you make so many assumptions in the way you pose it. No one has a special spyglass to see the code on your machine--next time share the actual code you've tried so we can see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to look into [`Enum.at/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#at/3).

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
middle_index = a |> length() |> div(2)
Enum.at(a, middle_index)
```

**Note:** This is expensive as it needs to traverse the entire list to find the length of the list, and then traverse halfway through the list to find what the actual element is. Generally speaking, if you need random access to an item in a list, you should be looking for a different data structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Right now, i'm converting a `range` to a list before finding the median of that list, but as you noted, that's expensive, especially if the list is really big. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to solve one of the excercises from "Programming Elixir 1.3": Guess which number user is thinking of between the range that user specifies, based only on too small / too big input. I feel like we're leaving the scope of the question now, though.

Comment: In that case, you have a min and max. To find the middle just do math on those two numbers. `div(min + max, 2)` will give you the same thing without converting things to lists and trying to traverse them.

Comment: Right, i'm a little embarassed that i didn't think of that before. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it:

`Enum.at(x, div(length(x), 2))`

[`Enum.at/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#at/3) retrieves the value at a particular index of an enumerable. `div/2` is the equivalent of the Python 2.x `/` integer division.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, thank you. I'm not sure how i missed `Enum.at/3`.